# MYSQL SELECT including COUNT within the same table with reference to specific column

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

So, I'm getting data from one table with a simple `SELECT` statement with `SELECT COUNT` included.

```
SELECT *, 
    (SELECT COUNT(`message_id`) 
    FROM `user_message` 
    WHERE `status_to` = 0
    ) AS `unread`  
FROM `user_message`
```

Here, `unread` counts for unread messages coming from other users. But that's not quite enough. What I want is to reference `SELECT COUNT` to a specific column, `user_id`, within the same table:

```
SELECT *, 
    (SELECT COUNT(`message_id`) 
    FROM `user_message` 
    WHERE `status_to` = 0 AND `user_message`.`user_id` = `user_message`.`user_id`
    ) AS `unread` 
FROM `user_message`
```

.. if that makes sense. My second statement disregards this part: `AND user_message.user_id = user_message.user_id`, and gives me the same result for each user_id.

What am I missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give different aliases to your table to get the related count

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT COUNT(`message_id`) 
    FROM `user_message` b 
    WHERE `status_to` = 0 
    AND `a`.`user_id` = `b`.`user_id`
    ) AS `unread`
FROM `user_message` a
```